# Show that the tangent of $C$ is a normal to the original curve.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $r(t)$ be a parametrization of a curve in $\mathbb R^2$ with curvature $K(t)\neq 0$ and normal vector $N(t)$. The parametrization $r_C(t)=r(t)+N(t)/K(t)$ defines another curve $C$. Show that the tangent of $C$ is a normal to the original curve.

Tangent of $C$ is $r_C'(t)=r'(t)+(K(t)N'(t)-N(t)K'(t))/K(t)^2=r'(t)+N'(t)/K(t)-N(t)K'(t)/K(t)^2$.

Then, we want to show $r_C'(t)\cdot r(t)=0$.

$r_C'(t)\cdot r(t)=r'(t)\cdot r(t)+N'(t)/K(t)\cdot r(t)-N(t)K'(t)/K(t)^2\cdot r(t)$.

Seems that the first two terms are 0, but the last one is not. I'm stuck here. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why do u think the last one should be zero? Don't we know $N\cdot r=0$, noting that $\kappa(t)$ is an scalar function?

Comment: @BabakS.: Definitely not. Note that we could translate the curve and change $r$ by a constant vector. This would not alter the geometry, but would alter such a computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always in differential geometry, you need to assume this is an arclength parametrization. (Most books and people will use $s$ for such a parameter.) And you need to use the Frenet equations (which hold only for an arclength parametrization): $T'(s) = K(s)N(s)$ and $N'(s) = -K(s)T(s)$.

P.S. Jason, you're also misinterpreting what they ask you to prove. You want to show $r_C'$ is orthogonal to $T$, not to $r$. That is, you want to show it is in the $N$ direction.

Comment: Do u think that the last term should be zero,Ted?

Comment: But the book didn't mention this to be arclength parametrization :(

Comment: I'm sorry, @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ, your book screwed up. These things happen. :( BTW, your presumption that $r\cdot r' = 0$ works only on a circle.

Comment: You're right about my misconception!.

Comment: But if it isn't a arc length prarametrization, does this formula still work?

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ: Indeed, this one does, so my apologies. The chain rule gives a factor of $ds/dt$ in front of *both* of the terms that cancel. Good observation.